# How to bind Product and Item in Entity Framework?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I have binding into the class, but not in another. I can`t call Product from Item: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Whats wrong?

How optimize this code?

```
foreach (var xd in excelData)
{
    Product p = new Product { 
        Name = xd.ProductName,
    };

    ctx.Products.Add(p);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    Item t = new Item { 
        Product=p,
    };

    t.ProductId = t.Product.ProductId;
    ctx.Items.Add(t);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    t.Product = ctx.Products.Where(c => c.ProductId == t.ProductId).FirstOrDefault();
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjectQuery.Include Method. Specifies the related objects to include in the query results.

```
ctx.Items.Include("Product").Where(c => c.SupplierId == id).ToList().ForEach(t =>
        {
            li.Add(new ShortPricesListItem()
            {
                Name = t.Product.Name,
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `ProducId` and ItemId`are auto generated you can write this with a single call to`SaveChanges` as follows

```
foreach (var xd in excelData)
{
    Product p = new Product { 
        Name = xd.ProductName,
    };

    Item t = new Item { 
        Product=p,
    };

    ctx.Items.Add(t);    
}

ctx.SaveChanges();
```